# GCPのインスタンスのイメージとして docker image を用いたい

Tags: docker, google-cloud

GCP の compute instance のイメージとして、docker image を指定することは可能でしょうか？

インスタンス上に docker container を立ち上げて、attach 等は出来るかと思うのですが、そもそものインスタンスのイメージに適用したいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: おそらく類似の記事。[Is there a way to directly deploy a container from docker hub to google compute engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50881454/9014308)

Comment: あるいはこちらでしょうか。[Docker のクイックスタート](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker?hl=ja)